# No data sent to MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm new to using MySQL with C# and I'm not understanding what's wrong here. My code is able to connect to my database but doesn't send any data even when there is text inside the 3 text boxes.

```
public static void testSendData ()
        {
            MainWindow form = new MainWindow();
            string input_username = form.textUsername.Text; 
            string input_password = form.textPassword.Text; 
            string input_email = form.textEmail.Text; 

            MySqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder(); 
            builder.Server = "localhost"; 
            builder.UserID = "root"; 
            builder.Password = "root"; 
            builder.Database = "authentication"; 
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(builder.ToString()); 
            connection.Open();
            string newuser_sql = "INSERT INTO `authentication`.`account` (`username`, `sha_pass_hash`, `email`) VALUES ('@username', '@pass', '@email');"; 
            MySqlCommand newuser = new MySqlCommand(newuser_sql, connection); 
            newuser.CommandText = newuser_sql; 
            newuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", input_username); 
            newuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", input_password); 
            newuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", input_email); 
            newuser.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
            MessageBox.Show("Worked."); 
        }
```

Edit: I updated my "newuser_sql" string and it will now send data, however it sends the literal @username, @pass, @email, to the database.

Comment: did you receive any errors?

Comment: No errors, when I look in my database I see that I have a new entry but no username, password, or email.

Comment: did you get any values from textboxes ?

Comment: Did you debug your code and see all your parameter values? What is your `ExecuteNonQuery` returns as a value?

Comment: did you try to insert direct values to database , i mean with out parameterised??

Comment: @ArunPrasanth "authentication" is the database name, "account" is the table name.

Comment: Are you sure you connected to the right database?

Comment: Updated the "newuser_sql" string, check my comment above.

Comment: Can you show us the result of the parameterized sql command? (thus the sql command included the put in parameters....naturally changed so that username, password and email are no longer real ones). That would answer the first question that comes to mind if the parameter variables are set to correct values

Comment: Here is a photo of what I see in the database. http://s24.postimg.org/vl501695h/mysql.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL .NET provider command parameter format is different from the typical ones.

Try this:

```
string newuser_sql = "INSERT INTO `authentication`.`account` (`username`, `sha_pass_hash`, `email`) VALUES (?username, ?pass, ?email);";
//..
newuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("?username", input_username); 
newuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("?pass", input_password); 
newuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("?email", input_email);
```

If this gives empty, then debug that `input_username`, `input_password` and `input_email` actually contain non-empty values

### Update

As it turns out, these days it should actually work with `@` too (just not with quotes around the parameters), so check that you are actually passing in any data (make a breakpoint and debug the value of `input_username` etc. when adding the parameters)

Comment: So the parameters would look like this? 

newuser.Parameters.AddWithValue(@username, input_username);

Comment: Nope, I mean the single quotes in the SQL query... `VALUES (?username, ?pass, ?email)` instead of `VALUES ('?username', '?pass', '?email')`, otherwise you are telling the query to insert the literal values (not the parameter values)

Comment: I did indeed get empty columns again, I'll have to debug and find out whats wrong.

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but you are instantiating a new form in your function (`MainWindow form = new MainWindow();`) which is not even shown, so the text boxes in that instance might be empty. Are you sure you are not filling your textboxes in other instance of `MainWindow`? Maybe the one created on the call to `Application.Run()` in `Program.cs`?

Comment: Yup, changed it to public static void testconnection (MainWindow form) and it worked!

Comment: That would have been obvious with some simple step-by-step debugging (it came obvious to me just by looking at the code, although the question was completely different), you should really do your homework. Glad you solved it though :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this part: (Modify the MySqlDbType on your end).

Remove the single quotes on the query.

Remove the `newuser.CommandText = newuser_sql;` since you already add the newuser_sql on the MySqlCommand parameter.

```
string newuser_sql = "INSERT INTO authentication.account (username, sha_pass_hash, email) VALUES (@username, @pass, @email)";
newuser.Parameters.Add("@username", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = input_username; 
newuser.Parameters.Add("@pass", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value =  input_password; 
newuser.Parameters.Add("@email", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = input_email;
```

Comment: The original code had no single quotes, adding them in seemed to work other than that it sends the literal "@username", "@pass", "@email", to the database.

Comment: I still get "@username" etc. in the database.

Comment: Updated answer. Can you verify if it's working for you?

Comment: Wait, can you confirm if you already refreshed your database query for the new values entered? and post the new database query image. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If removing the simple quotes on the insert doesn't change anything, I would try to insert the data without parameters:

```
      string newuser_sql = "INSERT INTO `authentication`.`account` (`username`, `sha_pass_hash`, `email`) VALUES ("+input_username"+, +"input_username"+, +"input_username");";
```

Just for test, if the problem are the parameters.

Comment: Tried it and got empty data in my columns.